# Can't index and search for special symbol ($ sign) in SOLR

Tags: apache, solr4, solrnet, solrcloud

I am using following tokenizer and filters while indexing my data.
Problem: i have some field which have just a single special character as content like $. Now standard tokenizer stripped it out. But if i use white space tokenizer it doesn't split the sentence at any punctuation characters.

> solr.StandardTokenizerFactory 
>   solr.StopFilterFactory
>   solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory
>   solr.StandardFilterFactory
>   solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory 
>   solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory
>   solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory 
>   solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory